# Recharts month XAxis calculation from epoch

Tags: reactjs, epoch, recharts

I've managed to generate a month XAxis in `recharts` from `epoch` data as shown in the example below:

```
const MonthChart = ({ data, domain, ...restProps }) => {
  const xFormatter = (seconds) =>
    new Date(seconds * 1000).toLocaleDateString("en-US", { month: "short" });

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="99%" height={400}>
      <ComposedChart
        data={data}
        margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <XAxis
          dataKey="epoch"
          type="number"
          domain={domain}
          interval={0}
          tickFormatter={xFormatter}
          tickCount={12}
        />
        <YAxis />
        <Area
          type="monotone"
          dataKey="range"
          fill="#b2b2b2 "
          stroke="#b2b2b2 "
          strokeDasharray="3 3"
        />
        <Line
          type="monotone"
          dataKey="average"
          stroke="#000"
          strokeDasharray="3 3"
        />
      </ComposedChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};
```

But for some reason "Sep" (September) is not being displayed, even if the dataset has records that contain epoch from this month.

Can you spot something wrong with my approach?

Thanks

Also here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/zotijs/pen/QWjqoOG?editors=0011) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by passing the "month" ticks manually to the `ticks` prop of `XAxis`.
For some reason the `tickFormatter` was not processing all the epochs.

Probably there is a better approach but this one did the trick for me.

The provided **codepen** to the question is updated with the workaround.

Also this is a small snippet of `XAxis`:

```
<XAxis
  dataKey="epoch"
  type="number"
  domain={domain}
  interval={0}
  tickFormatter={xFormatter}
  tickCount={12}
  ticks={manualTicks}
/>
```

`ticks` array:

```
const manualTicks = [
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 1, 1)),
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 2, 1)),
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 3, 1)),
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 4, 1)),
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 5, 1)),
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 6, 1)),
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 7, 1)),
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 8, 1)),
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 9, 1)),
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 10, 1)),
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 11, 1)),
  epochGenerator(new Date(YEAR, 12, 1)),
]
```

and `epochGenerator`:

```
const epochGenerator = (date) => date.getTime() / 1000;
```